# Add drop down list from geojson, csv files from Ipywidgets module using PYTHON

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, geemap

I am badly stuck with the problem of creating a drop-down list using Ipywidgets in python with files (JSON,GEOJSON,CSV)

> m = geemap.Map() url = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/New_SoilDB_RAW.geojson"
>
> m.add_point_layer(url, popup=["DISTRICTS", "Soil"], layer_name="Soil")
> m

## choose option

> from ipywidgets import VBox, Label, Dropdown, Output
>
> desc = Label("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/New_SoilDB.csv")
>
> dropdown = Dropdown(
> options=['Soil', 'DISTRICTS', 'LAT', 'LONG'],
> value='clay','Karimnagar',,
> disabled=False)
>
> output = Output()
>
> dropdown.observe(generate_plot, names="value")
>
> VBox([desc, dropdown, output])

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClFfq.png)

I am confused how to deal with the issue and any seek help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your error is, can you please include any error messages including the full stack trace.

I can see straight away that `'clay'` is not one of your listed options for your Dropdown.

dropdown = Dropdown( options=['Soil', 'DISTRICTS', 'LAT', 'LONG'], value='Soil', disabled=False)